# Unable to Click Submit button in webpage using .net

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, vba

Im creating a automation using VB in microsoft Visual Studio like a app 
the project path is Visual Basic>windows classic Desktop>windows form 
app(.NET framework). 
Code is written using VBA and it is a form which gets 
user input and paste it into a webform and click a submit button and create a Ticket.
I already have this automation running via VBA excel. however due to some circumstances i need to create it as a standalone app instead. I have problem in clicking the submit button. can someone please assist me in putting the code right.

this is the HTML element taken from view source

```
    <input type="hidden" name="ticket_type" id="ticket_type" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="quicklink_id" id="quicklink_id"value="0"/>
    <textarea name="work_log" style="display:none"></textarea>
    <textarea name="correspondence" style="display:none"></textarea>
    <div id="action_bar" class="cti-search-enabled">
    <div id="button_bar">
    <a class="tt_button orange_button" href="#" onclick="ajax_submit()">
    <span>Submit Ticket</span></a>
    <a class="tt_button" href="#" onclick="build_quicklink()">
    <span>Save as New Quicklink</span></a>
```

as you can see there are two buttons, one is Submit Ticket and Save as New Quicklink. i need to click the Submit Ticket button. The earlier code is used in VBA is

```
    Call sel.executeScript("ajax_submit()", "javascript")
```

This is my code in .net

```
     Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As System.Object, 
     ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) 
     Handles WebBrowser1.DocumentCompleted

     MessageBox.Show("Document loading completed!")
     Me.WebBrowser1.Document.ExecCommand("ajax_submit()", "javascript")
     End Sub
```

so once the form is loaded, it will show a message box and then should click the submit button. however this is showing error as

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30455 Argument not specified for parameter 'value' of 'Public Overloads Sub ExecCommand(command As String, showUI As Boolean, value As Object)'.  My_First

Can someone help me on how the code should be. Sorry im a beginner in .net (and VBA as well)

Comment: Try with `Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All("ID-Of-The-Button").InvokeMember("Click")`

Comment: the Button does not have any Id but have Class and name as below <a class="tt_button orange_button" href="#" onclick="ajax_submit()">
    <span>Submit Ticket</span></a>

Comment: Well, use the name then.

Comment: Got it Working, However im facing another problem now. its with the wait statement. neither Does Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000) or Do Until Me.WebBrowser1.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop seems to help, my tabs are empty and not filled

Comment: If this problem is directly related to your current question, edit it and add details of the problem. If not, make another question.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick:

```
Me.WebBrowser1.Document.All("ID-Of-The-Button").InvokeMember‌​("Click")
```